# Facebook Posting API Question

Tags: facebook

on my site right now I'm trying to have it post to a users wall a media file.
I had it working on the old api before, but now I'm trying to get it working on the new one and I'm having an issue.

I'm running this

```
$facebook->api_client->stream_publish($message, $attachment, $action_links);
```

Is that the old api or the new one? Because I'm getting this error

```
Call to a member function stream_publish() on a non-object in
```

I was reading a tutorial and it said to do this

```
$statusUpdate = $facebook->api('/me/feed', 'post', array('message'=> 'the message', 'cb' => ''));
```

but how can I post an attachment/ action links using that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, don't confuse APIs with SDKs.  The newest PHP SDK is capable of communicating with both the new Graph API and the old REST API.

And you *are* using the new SDK, since `Facebook::$api_client` doesn't exist in the new SDK.

Secondly, as is usual with most tutorials, they only show you a snapshot of the full features of a system. [See here](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/api#publishing) for more details about publishing with the Graph API.

However, you can still use the old API to publish your message like so

```
$facebook->api( array(
    'method'       => 'stream.publish'
  , 'target_id'    => $facebook->getUser()
  , 'message'      => $message
  , 'attachment'   => $attachment
  , 'action_links' => $action_links
) );
```

Comment: Trying to get this to work but struggling, can anyone help, looking to POST to a fan page with an mp3 media attachment. I can post a simple message but trying to add the media attachment array does not work.