# Posting Attachment Facebook Graph API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Right now I'm trying to figure out how to post an attachment using facebooks graph api.

Right now I'm using

```
            $attachment = array( 
                'message' => $_POST['tt'],
                'text' => 'Download',
                'name' => 'name', 
                'href' => 'http://www.url.com', 
                'description' => '  description!', 
                'media' => array(array(
                    'type' => 'mp3', 
                    'src' => $url, 
                    'href' => 'http://www.url.com/', 
                    'title' => $title,
                    'artist'=> 'artist',
                    'album'=>  'the album')));

        $statusUpdate = $facebook->api('/me/feed', 'post', $attachment);
```

Problem is it's only posting the message, nothing else, no attachment or anything.

Does anyone have any idea why?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Attachments aren't yet supported by the Graph API.

Per [the documentation](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/api#publishing)

> **Arguments** message, picture, link,
>   name, caption, description, source

See my answer in [your other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3354291) for a workaround.

Comment: Does the Graph API support attachments yet?

Answer (score 1):

You have to use the old php SDK until graph supports attachments... Graph only supports photoupload.
Im mixing Graph and old SDK without problems..