# collect picture from comments in facebook page status

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I currently need to collect pictures-comment (someone comment by pasting a picture) from facebook page group

I have done some research and find that

1.Support for this hasn't yet been added to the Graph API and as with many of the other messaging APIs, it's currently only avaialable for testing (i.e you must be a developer of the app to use it presently)
from
[View attachments in threads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9192430/view-attachments-in-threads)

2.You have to use the old php SDK until graph supports attachments
from
[Posting Attachment Facebook Graph API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3354489/posting-attachment-facebook-graph-api)

could any one provide some codes to me?
I need to know

1. Are the two approaches really works?? If yes, then... If no, I guess i will need to write/find a crawler (but it again sounds difficult as facebook group page is dynamic web)
2. What should I do if I want to follow 1st approach?
   Should I register as developer and set up an app and...? (I have no experience in setting up facebook app and would appreciate any useful step-by-step tutorial)
3. If I am going the 2nd approach (php SDK), are there are tutorial as I have no idea what should I do next.

I know java, c++ and little js but facebook apis are something really new to me.

Really appreciate any help.

Comment: None of the two questions you linked to are about _comments_. Using the Graph API, for a comment you can get the picture using the `attachment` field (but you have to explicitly request it).

Comment: The point is from my links people says "Attachments aren't yet supported by the Graph API."
"You have to use the old php SDK until graph supports attachments"
"Support for this hasn't yet been added to the Graph API and as with many of the other messaging APIs, it's currently only avaialable for testing (i.e you must be a developer of the app to use it presently)"

Comment: and when i use graph api explorer from fb with field=attachment, it just never works