# Send attachment inbox

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I want to send inbox messages on facebook with a attachment. Thats possible?

Reference: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/message/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Facebook does not allow to send messages to users using Graph API (avoiding spam) with 1 exception, as a page you can reply to messages from users.

The only way of sending messages like that is using the [Chat API (XMPP)](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/chat/) but it is more complex

Comment: the message is a friend<->friend message

Comment: They do not allow it using Graph API, also notice there is a read_inbox permissions but nothing that allows you to send

Comment: applications like tinychat send inbox message to friends on accept app,sure this not is possible?

Comment: hello, i tested the source off this api but dont work good, see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13976279/facebook-chat-send-message

Answer (score 0):

Not with the new Graph API, but the PHP-SDK; you can see it in the answer of Peter Bailey here:

[Facebook Posting API Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3354291/facebook-posting-api-question)

Comment: Testing this solution, a moment

Comment: tested this but publish on timeline, i want a inbox message